# How to update a database from windows application and view that data from an Android app?

Tags: android, database, windows, firebase, swing

I am developing a windows application using Java Swing. There is some data gathered using this application that I want to permanently store and also access that data in real time in an android app. I was planning to use a Fire Base database and upload data from swing directly to firebase database and access that in android app. My queries are:

1. Is there a way to do this using MySql instead of Firebase?
2. In case of an internet connection issue on the windows application, Is there a way to temporarily store that data in the system and when the system is back online upload the data on Firebase?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You are looking for opinions or alternatives.

Comment: Yes, you can make multiplatform apps using Firbase. I use Godot with httprequest commands, it works from any platform (windows, Android etc). I think you can make similar functions in any programming language, I tested Javascript, that worked too.